# Jetty and Dropwizard: how to return always 200 instead of 404, 500, etc

Tags: java, jersey, jetty, servlet-filters, dropwizard

I'm using Dropwizard 0.8.0 that comes with Jetty-Jersey-Jackson stack.
For security reasons, I want to add a filter that makes every request that passes through a particular route defined with Jersey returns always 200, even in case of error (4xx, 5xx, etc.).

Is this possibile with Jetty/Servlet filters? Can I intercept the request *after* it passed through Jersey resource (the controller), but before it is returned to client, in order to modify the http status code?

**UPDATE:**

I'm trying to do this with a ServletFilter, but it seems that the response is sent to client before my code is executed.
I've written the filter this way:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException
{
    if (response instanceof HttpServletResponse) {
        /* No pre-processing */

        chain.doFilter(request, response);

        /* Post-processing: */

        HttpServletResponse modifiedResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        if (modifiedResponse.getStatus() != 200) {
            modifiedResponse.setStatus(200);
        }
    }
}
```

With this, registered in Dropwizard with:

```
environment.servlets().addFilter("MyCustomFilter", new MyCustomFilter())
           .addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST), true, "/mypath/*");
```

The filter is executed, and in the access.log I see all the requests with status code 200; but the client always get the "real" status code (ex, a 404, or a "Method not allowed").
It seems that the response is sent to client before the last part of filter is executed.  Moreover, I can't modify the response body. I tried also with a HttpServletResponseWrapper, but with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm updating the question with my solution that finally works: I've used a Jersey filter instead of a Jetty http filtering, in order to manage directly the Response object from Jersey.

Obviously, this works only if you're using Jetty+Jersey, not with Jetty stand-alone.

Here's the filter I'm using:

```
/**
 * When active, this filter transforms all responses for specified basePath to 200, even in case of error.
 */
@Provider
public class DiscardErrors implements ContainerResponseFilter
{
    private String basePath;

    public DiscardErrors(String basePath)
    {
        this.basePath = basePath;
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext, ContainerResponseContext containerResponseContext) throws IOException
    {
        if containerRequestContext.getUriInfo().getPath().startsWith(this.basePath) {
            if (containerResponseContext.getStatus() != 200) { // Check if response code is different from 200
                containerResponseContext.setStatus(200); // Force 200 status code
                containerResponseContext.setEntity(""); // Empty body
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And register it in Dropwizard:

```
environment.jersey().register(new DiscardErrors("/"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create your custom `javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper<RuntimeException>`. In that case, every exception that you get from your server, you can resolve it to 200.

Check this [guy](http://gary-rowe.com/agilestack/2012/10/23/how-to-implement-a-runtimeexceptionmapper-for-dropwizard/) out. It should be easy to integrate with what you need.

Instead of what the tutorial shows you, like this example:

```
 if (webAppException.getResponse().getStatus() == 401) {
      return Response
        .status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED)
        .entity(new PublicFreemarkerView("error/401.ftl"))
        .build();
 }
```

You code will be

```
 if (webAppException.getResponse().getStatus() == 401) {
      return Response
        .status(Response.Status.OK)
        .build();
 }
```

Comment: Note that some errors cannot be handled this way (example: `400 Bad Request`).  This is because there is a class of errors that have no context and/or no request, so they cannot be sent down into user code for processing and response.

Comment: This is a nice idea, but with the ExceptionMapper I can't catch also the 2xx responses (ex: 204). I've updated my answer with a servlet filter. Unfortunately it doesn't work..